# repeateWhen rxJav -> rxJava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, publishsubject

I found examples with repeateWhen [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/rx-grokking-retrywhen-and-repeatwhen-on-android-development-examples-af5c3ed0872b)

```
 @NonNull
private final PublishSubject<Void> updateSubject = PublishSubject.create();
private void load() {
    repository
            .getSomething()
            .repeatWhen(repeatHandler ->
                                repeatHandler.flatMap(nothing -> updateSubject.asObservable()))
            .subscribe(result -> {}, err -> {});
}
```

But how to wright it on rxJava 2 ? Thre is not .asObservable() function and no examples! Please need you help

Comment: There was never the need for `asObservable` in the first place.

Comment: So answer is 
repeatHandler ->
                                repeatHandler.flatMap(nothing -> updateSubject))
Understanded ,thanks for response

Comment: `asObservable()` is now `hide()`, and it's used to hide PublishSubject consumer and only expose it as Observable